# Variable binding: moving a &mut or borrowing the referent?

Tags: rust

This code fails as expected at `let c = a;` with compile error "use of moved value: `a`":

```
fn main() {
    let a: &mut i32 = &mut 0;
    let b = a;
    let c = a;
}
```

a is moved into b and is no longer available for an assignment to c. So far, so good.

However, if I just annotate `b`'s type and leave everything else alone:

```
fn main() {
    let a: &mut i32 = &mut 0;
    let b: &mut i32 = a;
    let c = a;
}
```

the code fails again at `let c = a;`

But this time with a very different error message: "cannot move out of `a` because it is borrowed ... borrow of `*a` occurs here: `let b: &mut i32 = a;`"

So, if I just annotate `b`'s type: no move of `a` into `b`, but instead a "re"-borrow of `*a`?

What am I missing?

Cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So, if I just annotate `b`'s type: no move of `a` into `b`, but instead a "re"-borrow of `*a`?
>
> What am I missing?

Absolutely nothing, as in this case these two operations are semantically very similar (and equivalent if `a` and `b` belong to the same scope).

- Either you move the reference `a` into `b`, making `a` a moved value, and no longer available.
- Either you reborrow `*a` in `b`, making `a` unusable as long as `b` is in scope.

The second case is less definitive than the first, you can show this by putting the line defining `b` into a sub-scope.

This example won't compile because `a` is moved:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: &mut i32 = &mut 0;
    { let b = a; }
    let c = a;
}
```

But this one will, because once `b` goes out of scope `a` is unlocked:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: &mut i32 = &mut 0;
    { let b = &mut *a; }
    let c = a;
}
```

Now, to the question "Why does annotating the type of `b` change the behavior ?", my guess would be:

- When there is no type annotation, the operation is a simple and straightforward move. Nothing is needed to be checked.
- When there is a type annotation, a conversion may be needed (casting a `&mut _` into a `&_`, or transforming a simple reference into a reference to a trait object). So the compiler opts for a re-borrow of the value, rather than a move.

For example, this code is perflectly valid:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: &mut i32 = &mut 0;
    let b: &i32 = a;
}
```

and here moving `a` into `b` would not make any sense, as they are of different type. Still this code compiles: `b` simply re-borrows `*a`, and the value won't be mutably available through `a` as long as `b` is in scope.

Comment: Thx Levans for the answer. I actually checked the subscope variant before to verify that a borrow of `*a` actually took place. Could have been just a false compiler message, after all. Regarding your guess, I would feel very uncomfortable if anytime I use type annotation I would have to be prepared for some weird re-write of the obvious meaning: `let a = b;` should always be just a move or a copy, type annotated or not.

Comment: @dacker well, keep in mind that this behavior can *only* be reached with `&mut` references, in which case a re-borrow is simply a copy which respects the borrow rules.

Comment: But wasn't that a big point in all the docs I've read so far: &muts are always moved in these cases? NB: the same behavior as above happens with assignments to type annotated &muts as well.

Comment: Unless you are playing with nested scopes, re-borrowing or moving a `&mut` reference are effectively the same thing, so it's not surprising docs don't really make the distinction. And what do you call "type annotated &muts" ?

Comment: let b: &mut i32; b=a; Where else would I have to expect a non-move (e.g. a copy of some type) if it suits the compiler? Doesn't make me feel confident. But I'll accept your answer if that's the way it is.

Comment: The only non-reference types that are not moved are the ones implementing `Copy`, `&` references are `Copy`, and moving or re-borrowing a `&mut` reference are almost the same thing (and I don't see any situation where a move would be preferred over a re-borrow). That's basically all. Still, I'll open an issue in the compiler's Github to suggest they clarify it in the docs.

Comment: I see your point. My point is simply that the docs state something different than what's actually happening which, luckily in this case, does no harm. I can't think of an example that depends on a moved value actually being gone, either. Thx for the effort!

Answer (score 3):

To complement @Levans's answer on the specific question "Why does annotating the type change the behaviour?":

When you don't write the type, the compiler performs a simple move. When you do put the type, the `let` statement becomes a coercion site as documented in ["Coercion sites"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-sites):

> Possible coercion sites are:
>
> - let statements where an explicit type is given.

In the present case the compiler performs a *reborrow* coercion, which is a special case of coercion going from `&mut` to `&mut`, as explained in [this issue comment on GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35919#issuecomment-304130115).

Note that reborrowing in general and reborrow coercion in particular are currently poorly documented. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/788) on the Rust Reference to improve that point.