# Why is the mutable reference not moved here?

Tags: rust, move-semantics

I was under the impression that mutable references (i.e. `&mut T`) are always moved. That makes perfect sense, since they allow exclusive mutable access.
In the following piece of code I assign a mutable reference to another mutable reference and the original is moved. As a result I cannot use the original any more:

```
let mut value = 900;
let r_original = &mut value;
let r_new = r_original;
*r_original; // error: use of moved value *r_original
```

If I have a function like this:

```
fn make_move(_: &mut i32) {
}
```

and modify my original example to look like this:

```
let mut value = 900;
let r_original = &mut value;
make_move(r_original);
*r_original; // no complain
```

I would expect that the mutable reference `r_original` is moved when I call the function `make_move` with it. However that does not happen. I am still able to use the reference after the call.

If I use a generic function `make_move_gen`:

```
fn make_move_gen<T>(_: T) {
}
```

and call it like this:

```
let mut value = 900;
let r_original = &mut value;
make_move_gen(r_original);
*r_original; // error: use of moved value *r_original
```

The reference is moved again and therefore the program behaves as I would expect.
Why is the reference not moved when calling the function `make_move`?

[Code example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=74925cf82cca7907b571&version=nightly)

Comment: Explicitly instantiating (`make_move::<&mut i32>(r_original);`) works like the original function (no move). Fascinating; I'd assume borrow checking is happening before type inference.

Comment: From dacker's answer I assume that is the case: Explicitly annotating the type to be a mutable reference triggers a re-borrow of the contents instead of a move, leaving the original reference to be usable again once the new reference (here in make_move's scope) goes out of scope.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There might actually be a good reason for this.

`&mut T` isn't *actually* a type: all borrows are parametrized by some (potentially inexpressible) lifetime.

When one writes

```
fn move_try(val: &mut ()) {
    { let new = val; }
    *val
}

fn main() {
    move_try(&mut ());
}
```

the type inference engine infers `typeof new == typeof val`, so they share the original lifetime. This means the borrow from `new` does not end until the borrow from `val` does.

This means it's equivalent to

```
fn move_try<'a>(val: &'a mut ()) {
    { let new: &'a mut _ = val; }
    *val
}

fn main() {
    move_try(&mut ());
}
```

However, when you write

```
fn move_try(val: &mut ()) {
    { let new: &mut _ = val; }
    *val
}

fn main() {
    move_try(&mut ());
}
```

a cast happens - the same kind of thing that lets you cast away pointer mutability. This means that the lifetime is some (seemingly unspecifiable) `'b < 'a`. This involves a cast, and thus a reborrow, and so the reborrow is able to fall out of scope.

An always-reborrow rule would probably be nicer, but explicit declaration isn't too problematic.

Comment: I never thought of it that way. However it seems logical. By "cast away pointer mutability" you mean getting a shared reference from an mutable reference? Like let r: &i32 = r_mut; where r_mut is &mut i32.

Comment: Nice explanation. This really makes sense. My guess regarding `'b` would be: it's the intersection of `'a` which encompasses `move_try`'s body and the nested scope where `new` is defined; so `'b` would be this nested scope at the end of which `new`'s borrow ends.

Comment: As per the explaination, first 2 snippets seem equivalent but they show different error messages [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7863000c51a6497ffa2a26947cabb138). First snippet says value moved whereas second snippet says still borrowed. Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: @Mihir Technically `let new: &'a mut _ = val;` is a reborrow, it's just a no-op reborrow since the lifetimes are identical.

Comment: @Veedrac, it makes sense when you say "&mut T isn't actually a type". Although, I am curious,  `let new = val` moves the mutable reference. Then if we had to explicitly annotate `new` wanting data to be moved from `val` to `new`, how would be do that? `let new: _ = val`. What would be the exact type of `_`?

Comment: @Mihir I don't think you can, unless you have the whole type in a type variable.

Answer (score 5):

I asked something along those lines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535529/variable-binding-moving-a-mut-or-borrowing-the-referent).

It seems that in some (many?) cases, instead of a move, a re-borrow takes place. Memory safety is not violated, only the "moved" value is still around. I could not find any docs on that behavior either.

@Levans opened a github issue [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25899), although I'm not entirely convinced this is just a doc issue: dependably moving out of a &mut reference seems central to Rust's approach of ownership.

Answer (score 4):

It's `implicit reborrow`. It's a topic not [well documented](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/788).

This question has already been answered pretty well:

1. [how implicit reborrow works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62961289/5335565)
2. [how reborrow works along with borrow split](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68797851/5335565)

Answer (score 1):

If I tweak the generic one a bit, it would not complain either

```
fn make_move_gen<T>(_: &mut T) {
}
```

or

```
let _ = *r_original;
```

Comment: This doesn't really help answer the *"why"* behind this behavior. And the second example is just dereferencing and not really relevant here.

Comment: @kmdreko by second example, I meant if I changed "*r_original;" in the question's code block to "let _ = *r_original;", it would compile.
I was playing around and looks to me that when I do "let _ = r_original;", it would not do de-ref and thus it will not complain either even though the value has been moved indeed.

Comment: oh that's interesting! It does [remove the error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5cd25170e1d831be6abe2baca2bbe49). Sorry for misunderstanding, I've changed my vote.

Comment: thanks for the comment though, I have long been a pure consumer and learning to contribute a bit back :)