# Type inference and borrowing vs ownership transfer

Tags: rust, ownership

I am learning Rust and I've run into some confusing behaviour. The following code compiles fine and works as expected (**edit**: added code other than test function, previously omitted):

```
struct Container<'a> {
    contents : &'a mut i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut one = Container { contents: &mut 5 };
    test(&mut one);
    println!("Contents: {}",one.contents);
}

fn test<'a>(mut x : &'a mut Container) {
    *x.contents += 1;
    let y = x;
    *y.contents += 1;
    x = y;
    println!("{:?}",*x.contents)
}
```

Now in the statement

```
let y = x;
```

the type is inferred. Because `x` is of type `&'a mut Container`, I thought that this would be equivalent:

```
let y: &'a mut Container = x;
```

But when I do that, the compiler takes issue:

```
test_3.rs:25:5: 25:10 error: cannot assign to `x` because it is borrowed
test_3.rs:25     x = y;
                 ^~~~~
test_3.rs:23:33: 23:34 note: borrow of `x` occurs here
test_3.rs:23     let y: &'a mut Container = x;
```

How is `x` not borrowed by that point in the correctly working example? I tested by omitting the line `x = y;` from the correctly working version and the compiler said:

```
test_3.rs:24:13: 24:14 note: `x` moved here because it has type `&mut Container<'_>`, which is moved by default
```

So I'm getting a move when I don't explicitly define the type but a borrow otherwise. What is going on, how do I get the same behavior as before while explicitly giving the type, and what is causing move behavior in one case but borrow in the other?

**Edited with full program**

Comment: Perhaps an [example like this](http://is.gd/Ht32Jl)?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry; here's a [the full code](http://is.gd/9oz2kT). Your example captures the problem exactly.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32154387/1763356

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do

```
let y = x;
```

a move happens. `x` is emptied, so to speak, and ownership is transferred to `y`.

When you do either of

```
let y: &mut _ = x;
let y: &'a mut _ = x;
```

`x` is reborrowed to aid matching the lifetimes. This roughly translates to

```
let y: &mut _ = &mut *x;
let y: &'a mut _ = &mut *x;
```

This leaves `x` non-empty, holding an aliased mutable borrow. Assigning to it thus must wait for `y` to be destroyed. Alternatively, you can pre-move it

```
let tmp = x;
let y: &'a mut _ = tmp;
```

I'll admit it's nonobvious behaviour, and it's a shame that you can't borrow the contents of a value without borrowing the whole value.

Comment: *holding an aliased mutable borrow* — I was under the impression that that is distinctly a thing that safe Rust forbids?

Comment: Rust doesn't forbid aliased mutable borrows - it forbids using more than one at a time, or overlapping them in non-lexical ways. When you write `&mut x`, `x` is still a valid stack location - it just isn't legal to read or write to it.

Comment: Interesting. I always wondered what exact rules were the compiler uses to determine move-vs-reborrow. Up until now, I assumed reborrowing only happens in function calls where the function takes a `&mut`. But apparently, being more explicit *within* a function also qualifies for a reborrow.