# Is it possible to create a wrapper around an &mut that acts like an &mut

Tags: rust

The following code fails to compile because MutRef is not `Copy`. It can not be made copy because `&'a mut i32` is not Copy. Is there any way give MutRef similar semantics to `&'a mut i32`?

The motivation for this is being able to package up a large set of function parameters into a struct so that they can be passed as a group instead of needing to be passed individually.

```rust
struct MutRef<'a> {
    v: &'a mut i32
}

fn wrapper_use(s: MutRef) {
}

fn raw_use(s: &mut i32) {
}

fn raw_ref() {
    let mut s: i32 = 9;
    let q = &mut s;
    raw_use(q);
    raw_use(q);

}

fn wrapper() {
    let mut s: i32 = 9;
    let q = MutRef{ v: &mut s };
    wrapper_use(q);
    wrapper_use(q);
}
```

Comment: [Relevant Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/46qwjv/why_can_i_use_an_mut_reference_twice/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The name for this feature is "implicit reborrowing" and it happens when you pass a `&mut` reference where the compiler expects a `&mut` reference of a possibly different lifetime. The compiler only implicitly reborrows when the actual type and the expected type are both `&mut` references. It does not work with [generic arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143889/retaking-ownership-of-a-mutable-reference-passed-to-a-function-accepting-a-gener) or structs that contain `&mut` references. There is no way in current Rust to make a custom type that can be implicitly reborrowed. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1403) about this limitation dating from 2015, but so far nobody has proposed any way to lift it.

You can always implement your own method to *explicitly* reborrow:

```
impl<'a> MutRef<'a> {
    // equivalent to fn reborrow(&mut self) -> MutRef<'_>
    fn reborrow<'b>(&'b mut self) -> MutRef<'b> {
        MutRef {v: self.v}
    }
}

fn wrapper() {
    let mut s: i32 = 9;
    let mut q = MutRef{ v: &mut s };
    wrapper_use(q.reborrow());  // does not move q
    wrapper_use(q);             // moves q
}
```

#### See also

- [Why is the mutable reference not moved here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154387/why-is-the-mutable-reference-not-moved-here)
- [Type inference and borrowing vs ownership transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067664/type-inference-and-borrowing-vs-ownership-transfer)