# Swapping two local references leads to lifetime error

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

I have two variables of type `&T`, `x` and `y`, which I swap locally inside a function:

```
pub fn foo<T: Copy>(mut x: &T) {
    let y_owned = *x;
    let mut y = &y_owned;
    for _ in 0..10 {
        do_work(x, y);
        std::mem::swap(&mut x, &mut y);
    }
}

fn do_work<T>(_x: &T, _y: &T) {}
```

This code fails to compile, giving the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `y_owned` does not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:3:22
  |
3 |         let mut y = &y_owned;
  |                      ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
8 |     }
  |     - borrowed value only lives until here
  |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the function body at 1:5...
 --> src/lib.rs:1:5
  |
1 | /     pub fn foo<T: Copy>(mut x: &T) {
2 | |         let y_owned = *x;
3 | |         let mut y = &y_owned;
4 | |         for _ in 0..10 {
... |
7 | |         }
8 | |     }
  | |_____^
```

I fail to see why it shouldn't work. `x` and `y` have different lifetimes, but why should the compiler require `y` to live as long as `x`? I am  only modifying references locally inside `foo` and referenced objects are guaranteed to exist. Once `foo` returns, it doesn't matter if these `x` and `y` even existed, does it?

For larger context, I am implementing mergesort and want to swap the primary and auxiliary (temporary) arrays this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Obviously, `x` and `y` have different lifetimes, but why should compiler require `y` to live as long as `x`?

Because of the signature of [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html):

```
pub fn swap<T>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T)
```

`T` is the type of the argument to `foo`, which is a reference of some lifetime *chosen by the caller of `foo`*. In the 2018 edition of Rust, the latest compiler gives a slightly more detailed error message in which it calls this lifetime `'1`. Calling `std::mem::swap` requires the type of `x`, `&'1 T`, to be the same as the type of `y`, but it can't shrink the lifetime of `x` to match that of `y` because the lifetime of `x` is chosen by the *caller*, not by `foo` itself. [Vikram's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53836464/3650362) goes into more detail on why the lifetime cannot be shrunk in this case.

> I am essentially only modifying references locally inside foo and referenced objects are guaranteed to exist

This is true, but it doesn't give you any freedom with respect to the lifetime of `x` inside `foo`. To make `foo` compile, you have to give the compiler another degree of freedom by making a new borrow of which the compiler can choose the lifetime. This version will compile ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d567a51b557d2ab617c25d2139c8d306)):

```
pub fn foo<T: Copy>(x: &T) {
    let mut x = &*x;
    ...
}
```

This is called *reborrowing*, and it happens implicitly in some cases, [for example, to the receiver of a method call that takes `&mut self`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154387/why-is-the-mutable-reference-not-moved-here). It does not happen implicitly in the case you presented because `swap` is not a method.

Answer (score 5):

It is helpful to compile this program with the latest stable toolchain on the 2018 Edition, since it improves the error message a bit:

```
error[E0597]: `y_owned` does not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:4:17
  |
1 | pub fn foo<T: Copy>(mut x: &T) {
  |                            - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
4 |     let mut y = &y_owned;
  |                 ^^^^^^^^
  |                 |
  |                 borrowed value does not live long enough
  |                 assignment requires that `y_owned` is borrowed for `'1`
...
9 | }
  | - `y_owned` dropped here while still borrowed
```

What happens is:

- the input `x` is a reference with the arbitrary lifetime `'1` established by the caller.
- The variable `y` is a reference created locally, and as such it has lifetime "shorter" than `'1`.

As such, you cannot pass the reference in `y` to `x`, even if it may seem safe to, because `x` expects something that lives at least for the lifetime indicated by the caller.

One possible solution is to create a second copy of the value behind x, and borrow that locally.

```
pub fn foo<T: Copy>(x: &T) {
    let mut x = &*x;
    let mut y = &*x;
    for _ in 0..10 {
        do_work(x, y);
        std::mem::swap(&mut x, &mut y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Mutable references are invariant over the type they refer to. If you have `&'a mut T`, then it is invariant over `T`. The signature of `swap()` expects same types with same lifetimes on both the input arguments. i.e they both are mutable references to `T`.

Let's look at your problem:

The argument to `foo()` is `&T` and with lifetimes it will be `foo<'a, T: Copy>(mut x: &'a T)` and this lifetime is given by the caller. Within the function you have a local variable `y_owned` and you take a reference to it with some local lifetime. So at this point we have `&'a T` which is the input argument with lifetime set by the caller and `&'local y_owned`  with some local lifetime. All good!

Next, you call `swap()` and pass to it, mutable references (`&mut &T` and `&mut &y_owned`) to the aforementioned references. Now, here's the catch; Since they are mutable references and as mentioned they are invariant over what they point to;  `x` which is `&'a T` will not shrink down to the scope of the function call , as a result `y` which is `&'local y_owned` will also now be expected to be `&'a y_owned`, which is not possible, since `'a` goes beyond `y_owned`, hence it complains that `y_owned` does not live long enough.

For more, please refer [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html)

Answer (score 3):

The lifetime information of a reference is part of its type. Since Rust is a statically typed language, the lifetime of a reference variable can't dynamically change at runtime.

The lifetime of the reference `x` is specified by the caller, and it must be longer than everything that is created inside the function. The lifetime of `y` is the lifetime of a variable local to the funciton, and as such is shorter than the lifetime of `x`. Since the two lifetimes don't match, you can't swap the variables, since you can't dynamically change the type of a variable, and the lifetime is part of its type.