# Do mutable references have move semantics?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut name = String::from("Charlie");
    let x = &mut name;
    let y = x;       // x has been moved
    say_hello(y);
    say_hello(y);       // but y has not been moved, it is still usable
    change_string(y);
    change_string(y);  

}

fn say_hello(s: &str) {
    println!("Hello {}", s);
}

fn change_string(s: &mut String) {
    s.push_str(" Brown");
}
```

When I assign `x` to `y` `x` has been moved. However, I would expect something with move semantics to be moved when I use it in a function. However, I can still use the reference after subsequent calls. Maybe this has to do with say_hello() taking a immutable reference but change_string() takes a mutable reference but the reference is still not moved.

Answer (score 56):

You are completely right with both your reasoning and your observations. It definitely looks like things *should* be happening the way you describe it. However, the compiler applies some convenience magic here.

Move semantics generally apply in Rust for all types that do not implement the `Copy` trait. Shared references are `Copy`, so they are simply copied when assigned or passed to a function. Mutable references are not `Copy`, so they should be moved.

That's where the magic starts. Whenever a mutable reference is assigned to a name with a type already known to be a mutable reference by the compiler, the original reference is *implicitly reborrowed* instead of being moved. So the function call

```
change_string(y);
```

is transformed by the compiler to mean

```
change_string(&mut *y);
```

The original reference is derefenced, and a new mutable borrow is created. This new borrow is moved into the function, and the original borrow gets released once the function returns.

Note that this isn't a difference between function calls and assignments. Implicit reborrows happen whenever the target type is already known to be a mutable reference by the compiler, e.g. because the pattern has an explicit type annotation. So this line also creates an implicit reborrow, since we explicitly annotated it as a mutable reference type:

```
let y: &mut _ = x;
```

This function call on the other hand moves (and thus consumes) the mutable reference `y`:

```
fn foo<T>(_: T) {}

[...]
foo(y);
```

The generic type `T` here isn't explicitly a mutable reference type, so no implicit reborrow occurs, even though the compiler infers that the type is a mutable reference – just as in the case of your assignment `let y = x;`.

In some cases, the compiler can infer a generic type is a mutable reference even in the absence of an explicit type annotation:

```
fn bar<T>(_a: T, _b: T) {}

fn main() {
    let mut i = 42;
    let mut j = 43;
    let x = &mut i;
    let y = &mut j;
    bar(x, y);   // Moves x, but reborrows y.
    let _z = x;  // error[E0382]: use of moved value: `x`
    let _t = y;  // Works fine. 
}
```

When inferring the type of the first parameter, the compiler doesn't know yet it's a mutable reference, so no implicit reborrow occurs and `x` is moved into the function. However, when reaching the second parameter, the compiler has already inferred that `T` is a mutable reference, so `y` is implicitly reborrowed. (This example is a good illustration why adding compiler magic to make things "just work" generally is a bad idea. Explicit is better than implicit.)

Unfortunately, [this behaviour currently isn't documented in the Rust reference](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/788).

See also:

- [Stuff the Identity Function Does (in Rust)](https://bluss.github.io/rust/fun/2015/10/11/stuff-the-identity-function-does/)
- [Discussion of the topic on the Rust users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/questions-about-mut-t-and-move-semantics-mut-t-is-move-only/37484)
- [Why is the mutable reference not moved here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154387/why-is-the-mutable-reference-not-moved-here)

Comment: What is the benefit of re-borrow? Does it improve performance? Does it prevent some kind of bugs?

Comment: @Shiva The alternative would be to move the mutable reference, which means it couldn't be used again. Performance isn't affected in any way – the generated code should be more or less identical. The difference is how the borrow checker interprets it.