# Obtain a mutable reference to a immutable variable?

Tags: rust

Here's the code, since `a` is declared as immutable, we can't obtain a mutable reference from `a`, right? But this one has compiled, why is that?

```rust
struct Foo;

fn main() {
    let a = &mut Foo;
    a.mut_ref();
}

impl Foo {
    fn mut_ref(&mut self) { }
}
```

[code-link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5bc97fef5cd38b0669e667a9e333205b)

Comment: You don't actually obtain a mutable reference to `a` in this code, but this is still a good question. I know it *is* this way but I couldn't explain it mechanically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the variable `a` is `&mut Foo`, i.e. `a` itself is a mutable reference to a `Foo` object. Mutating `a` would mean to make it point to a different `Foo` object. Since `a` itself is immutable, you can't change what `a` is pointing to, and your code does not disprove this in any way.

Your code simply passes the `&mut Foo` as the `self` parameter to `mut_ref()` – note that the type of `self` is also `&mut Foo`. No auto-dereferencing is happening – `a` already has exactly the type that is epxected for the `self` parameter. However, we are [triggering an implicit reborrow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62960584) here, so the call is equivalent to `Foo::mut_ref(&mut *a)`. This implicit reborrow isn't what's making the code work, though – moving the mutable reference out of `a` would also be perfectly allowed.

While `a` is immutable as a variable, it's still a mutable reference, so you can mutate the `Foo` object it's pointing to (assuming `Foo` had any state to mutate). You can't obtain a mutable reference to `a`, which would need to have the type `&mut &mut Foo`.