# Why doesn't a trait object move when it calls enumerate()？

Tags: rust, iterator, move, ownership, trait-objects

Let me give the code first

```rust
fn dump(iter: &mut dyn Iterator<Item=String>) {
    for (i, v) in iter.enumerate() {
        println!("{} {}", i, v);
    }
    for v in iter {
        println!("{}", v);
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_trait() {
    let v = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string()];
    let mut iter = v.into_iter();
    dump(&mut iter);
}
```

Here is the output when I run this test

> running 1 test
>
> `0 a`
>
> `1 b`
>
> `2 c`
>
> test test_trait ... ok

Why the **iter** not moved when calling **enumerate**?

The **enumerate** is accepting **self** as its first argument, so I think it should move the **iter**,
but it doesn't!  The second for-loop can still run, without any compilation error.

Comment: let me clear my thought.  `&mut dyn Iterator<Item=String>` somehow implements the `Iterator<Item=String>` trait, so `iter` can call `enumerate` function, and because the `Self` is `&mut`, so `iter` is not moved according to the answer mentioned above. And also `&mut dyn Iterator<Item=String>` implements `IntoIterator`, so the `iter.into_iter()` is called in the second for-loop. This time `Self` is also `&mut`( I guess), why moved?

Comment: Here is an [explanation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#for-loops-and-intoiterator) of why iter would be moved by for-loop. It is not moved by enumerate because of re-borrowing explained in the reference [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960584/do-mutable-references-have-move-semantics).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `Self` is actually `&mut (dyn Iterator<Item = String>)` making the `enumerate` call return `Enumerate<&mut (dyn Iterator<Item = String>)>`. I am not that familiar how Rust deals with this kind of dynamic trait objects but my guess is that what gets dropped at the end of enumeration is actually the reference.

By the way - if you are using VSCode and the Rust analyzer extension, you can turn on the  "Inlay Hints: Type Hints" option to see the types of things.
There is a similar option for the Intellij Idea IDE that I can not remember off the top of my head. That way I was able to see the type by making a variable of the enumeration and this is what it showed:

```rust
let a: Enumerate<&mut (dyn Iterator<Item = String>)>
```

Comment: but the second loop does move the `iter`, because if I add a third loop `for v in iter`, compiler will tell me it is moved