# What are the differences between my for loop variations in Rust?

Tags: for-loop, rust, compiler-errors

I am teaching myself Rust by reading through "the book". When I was working on the first exercise from this link: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html, I found getting the types correct with for loop was really tricky. I eventually got the code to work by trial and error, but I am really confused by how it works.

Here I simplified some of the issues I ran into and left my questions inline. I tried as many variations as I could but I think the main confusions are:

- the difference between `loop1` and `loop2` (I believe 3 and 4, 5 and 6 are analogous)
- The inline question in `loop1` and `loop2`
- What is the problem with `loop3_bad`?

```
    fn main() {
        // using mut because it is needed in the original code
        let mut list = vec![10, 14, 10, 12, 9, -2, 14, 10, 14];
        
        let ret1 = loop1(&list);
        let ret2 = loop2(&list);
        // let ret3 = loop3_bad(&mut list);
        let ret4 = loop4(&mut list);
        let ret5 = loop5(&mut list);
        let ret6 = loop6(&mut list);
        let ret7 = loop7(&mut list);
    
        println!("loop1 ret={:?}", ret1);
        println!("loop2 ret={:?}", ret2);
        // println!("loop3 ret={:?}", ret3);
        println!("loop4 ret={:?}", ret4);
        println!("loop5 ret={:?}", ret5);
        println!("loop6 ret={:?}", ret6);
        println!("loop7 ret={:?}", ret7);
    }
    
    fn loop1(list: &Vec<i32>) -> Option<f64> {
        if list.is_empty() {
            None
        } else {
            let mut sum: f64 = 0.0;
            for &i in list {
                sum += f64::from(i);
                // cannot write f64::from(*i)
                // error would be:
                // error[E0614]: type `i32` cannot be dereferenced
                //
                // How should I read the for syntax?
                // Is it because "&i" of &i32 type, therefore i is of "i32" type?
                // or should I treat "&i" a declaration that i is of "&i32" type?
            }
            Some(sum/list.len() as f64)
        }
    }
    
    fn loop2(list: &Vec<i32>) -> Option<f64> {
        if list.is_empty() {
            None
        } else {
            let mut sum: f64 = 0.0;
            for i in list {
                sum += f64::from(*i);
                // cannot write f64::from(i)
                // error would be:
                // the trait `From<&i32>` is not implemented for `f64`
                //
                // is i of "&i32" type?
                // is the dereferencing required here?
            }
            Some(sum/list.len() as f64)
        }
    }
    
    // This one causes compilation error, but why?
    // If `list` is moved by the loop, why didn't this cause issue in loop1()?
    //
    // Rust ERROR:
    //
    // error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `list`
    //    --> for_loop_example.rs:65:18
    //     |
    // 57  | fn loop3(list: &mut Vec<i32>) -> Option<f64> {
    //     |          ---- move occurs because `list` has type `&mut Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    // ...
    // 62  |         for &mut i in list {
    //     |                       ----
    //     |                       |
    //     |                       `list` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
    //     |                       help: consider borrowing to avoid moving into the for loop: `&list`
    // ...
    // 65  |         Some(sum/list.len() as f64)
    //     |                  ^^^^ value borrowed here after move
    //     |
    // note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `list`
    // 
    
    // fn loop3_bad(list: &mut Vec<i32>) -> Option<f64> {
    //     if list.is_empty() {
    //         None
    //     } else {
    //         let mut sum: f64 = 0.0;
    //         for &mut i in list {
    //             sum += f64::from(i);
    //         }
    //         Some(sum/list.len() as f64)
    //     }
    // }
    
    fn loop4(list: &mut Vec<i32>) -> Option<f64> {
        if list.is_empty() {
            None
        } else {
            let mut sum: f64 = 0.0;
            for i in &*list {
                // what does &*list even do?
                sum += f64::from(*i);
            }
            Some(sum/list.len() as f64)
        }
    }
    
    fn loop5(list: &mut Vec<i32>) -> Option<f64> {
        if list.is_empty() {
            None
        } else {
            let mut sum: f64 = 0.0;
            for &i in &*list { // similar to loop4, excpet for using &i
                sum += f64::from(i);
            }
            Some(sum/list.len() as f64)
        }
    }
    
    fn loop6(list: &mut Vec<i32>) -> Option<f64> {
        if list.is_empty() {
            None
        } else {
            let mut sum: f64 = 0.0;
            for &mut i in &mut *list { // looking similar to loop5
                sum += f64::from(i);
            }
            Some(sum/list.len() as f64)
        }
    }
    
    fn loop7(list: &mut Vec<i32>) -> Option<f64> {
        if list.is_empty() {
            None
        } else {
            let mut sum: f64 = 0.0;
            for i in &mut *list { // looking similar to loop4, except for using mut
                sum += f64::from(*i);
            }
            Some(sum/list.len() as f64)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few building blocks here.

When you iterate over `&Vec`, you get back shared references to its contents. That is, iterating over `&Vec<i32>` will give you elements of type `&i32`. When you iterate over `&mut Vec`, you get back mutable references - `&mut i32` - that allow you to change, and not only inspect, the contents (also, when you iterate over `Vec` you get owned `i32`, but that is not relevant to our discussion).

The second thing important to know is that in Rust, there are actually *two* ways to dereference a reference: the first being the usual `*`, the second is using patterns. When I bind a new variable,

```
let x = value;
```

`x` is actually not just a name, but a [pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html) (an [irrefutable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#refutability) one). I used [identifier pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#identifier-patterns) that allows me to just bind the value to  a name, but there are other kinds too. One of them is [the reference pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns): `&` or `&mut` then a nested pattern. What it does is dereferencing the value and then binding the nested pattern to the dereferenced value. So, the following:

```
let &i = &value;
```

Is equivalent to `let i = value;` (you can also see the symmetry, which is why this syntax was chosen).

Not just `let` permits patterns: any binding in Rust does. Parameters, `match` arguments, and also, `for` loops.

Armed with this knowledge let's understand the loops one by one:

In `loop1`, we're iterating over `&Vec<i32>`. This gives us `&i32`s. However, we're using `&i` is the pattern - that means `i` is only bound to the `i32` part. Since this is not a reference you cannot dereference it anymore.

`loop2` is the same but without the reference pattern. Here `i` is `&i32`, so you must dereference it.

`loop3_bad` is interesting. It does the same of `loop1` but with mutable references. But it does not work. Shared references are `Copy`, and so you can access `list` even after it was moved by the loop - but mutable references are not, and so the compiler errs with "borrow of moved value".

The rest of the loops are performing a so-called *reborrow*, with already explained various combinations of shared/mutable references and using/not using reference patterns. A reborrow is just `&*` or `&mut *`, and that is dereferencing then immediately taking a reference. Doesn't sound interesting, and indeed it has no effect for shared references, but for mutable references it has important semantics: you cannot *copy* a mutable reference, but you can *reborrow* it. `&mut *v` gives you an access to a potentially-shorter lifetime, without affecting the original reference. Once the reborrowed reference is no longer needed, you can discard it and use the original reference again.

Since we only reborrow, `list` is not moved. Usually the compiler is performing a reborrow automatically - see [Do mutable references have move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960584/do-mutable-references-have-move-semantics/62961289#62961289) - but with `for` loops, it does not. This is why `loop3` failed without the reborrowing, but `loop5` succeeeds

As an aside, do not take `&Vec<i32>` as parameter, use `&[i32]` instead: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o)

Comment: In addition to this explanation, I just wanted to add one thing. We know all these implementations are functionally identical and the compiler does too. If you show the assembly in release mode on Rust playground, you can see it just compiles the first function then links the rest of them to that symbol. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=d4f3659aafebbc2393c5faa072eadeb8

Comment: @Chayim Friedman, thank you for the comprehensive reply. I am wondering, from a performance/maintainability/readability perspective, whether these loops are identical or some of them are better than others.

Comment: @Locke, very interesting. Let me play with that

Comment: I just looked at the Assembly result, they all point to loop1 under release mode. Regarding my previous comment question, there is really no performance difference.