# In Rust, what the mechanism of transferring a mutable reference into a function?

Tags: rust

I'm just a rookie in `Rust` and I feel a bit confused about this point. To cite an example:

```rust
fn func(s_ref: &mut str) {}

fn main() {
    let mut word = "hello".to_string();
    let s: &mut str = &mut word;
    func(s);
}
```

Before discussing Rust, I wanna tell something about C++ to better clarify Rust.

So, in `C++`, if we pass a pointer `s` into a function as its parameter named `s_ref`, then the pointer itself will be copied as a temporary variable for the internal usage within the invoked function, and `s_ref` will be automatically freed when it reaches the end of scope, right?

When it comes to `Rust`, I think it's the same. Because reference (or pointer) is a **simple data type** (like i32), so the passed reference `s` will be **generated a copy** named `s_ref`. But if so, there're two mutable references for the same variable `word`, violating the defined rule of Rust.

I know I made someone mistake but I'm not able to pinpoint it. Would you please give a favor? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See also [Do mutable references have move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960584/do-mutable-references-have-move-semantics)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks. That's informative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are close, but you are missing one key detail.

In Rust, assignment (including that of a function parameter) happens by *moving* the value, unless the value's type implements `Copy`, in which case it is copied.  In C++ you have to request a move with `std::move()` (in the cases where it's not implicit), whereas in Rust, moving is *automatic* for values that cannot be copied, and a move vacates the original variable such that trying to read from it again results in a compile-time error.

The `Copy` trait is implemented for all shared references (`&T`) but it is *not* implemented for mutable references (`&mut T`).

However, the compiler does a sneaky thing in this particular case.  If the the reference were moved, then `s` would be in a "moved from" state after the call to `func()` and so you would expect that you couldn't use it anymore... but you can!

```
func(s);
func(s);
```

This compiles.  So what's going on?

The compiler inserts a *reborrow* here, as though you had written this:

```
func(&mut *s);
```

This kind of construct asks the compiler *not* to consume the reference `s` and instead reborrow its referent.  (This happens implicitly when passing references to functions, as is happening here, but there are other cases where it's *not* implicit and you have to explicitly reborrow.)

> But if so, there're two mutable references for the same variable `word`, violating the defined rule of Rust.

Ah, but that's not *quite* the rule.  The rule is that, at any given moment, a value can be either:

- Readable by any number of names, *or*
- Writable by *at most one name.*

This doesn't mean that you can't have two mutable references to the same value, it just means that only one can be usable at a time.

In your code, `main()` transfers control to `func()` after reborrowing `s`.  This means that `s` cannot be used until `s_ref` goes away -- but it *could not possibly be used* until `s_ref` goes away, because `func()` has to return before `s` could be used again.

So as you can see, this doesn't violate Rust's aliasing rules.  When you call `func()`, the value `word` can be written to using `s_ref`, but it cannot be written to using `s` until the function returns.  Then `s` is usable again.

We can demonstrate this with the following two programs:

```
fn func(s_ref: &mut str) {}

fn main() {
    let mut word = "hello".to_string();
    let s: &mut str = &mut word;
    
    let s2: &mut str = &mut *s;
    func(s2);
    
    func(s);
}
```

This compiles!  We reborrow `s` into `s2`, but we don't use `s` until we stop using `s2`.  The compiler figures this out by itself (see [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/501250)).

However, if we interleave the usages then we have a problem:

```
fn func(s_ref: &mut str) {}

fn main() {
    let mut word = "hello".to_string();
    let s: &mut str = &mut word;
    let s2: &mut str = &mut *s;
    
    func(s);
    func(s2);
}
```

Now the compiler will complain:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*s` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:8:10
  |
6 |     let s2: &mut str = &mut *s;
  |                        ------- first mutable borrow occurs here
7 |     
8 |     func(s);
  |          ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
9 |     func(s2);
  |          -- first borrow later used here
```

Between lines 6 and 9, `s` and `s2` are both considered to be usable, and this is disallowed.

As you can see, there is no problem having multiple mutable references to the same value.  However, it's not permitted for their usage to overlap.  As long as they don't overlap, there isn't an issue.

Comment: Incredible! Your explanation is so clear and lucid so that even though I've not learnt reborrow mechanism yet, I still could understand more than the question itself. Thank you pretty much!

Answer (score 2):

> But if so, there're two mutable references for the same variable word, violating the defined rule of Rust.

It does not, because the borrows are nested, so `s_ref` is treated as a sub-borrow of `s`: as long as `s_ref` exists, `s` can't be used.

You can see this if you return `s_ref` from `func` and try to access both it and the original (or include some code which uses the returned `s_ref` after printing `s`, to make sure it doesn't get dropped):

```rust
fn func(s_ref: &mut str) -> &mut str {s_ref}

fn main() {
    let mut word = "hello".to_string();
    let s: &mut str = &mut word;
    let u = func(s);
    println!("{s} {u}"); // cannot borrow `s` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Is "sub-borrow" equal to "reborrow" mechanism?