# Implicit type producing a compiler error only when println!() is present

Tags: rust

I'm a beginner to the Rust programming language, and I'm trying to create a toy program where I declare a (mutable) integer, but instead of changing that integer directly, I create a mutable reference to it and change it through there.  Additionally, I want to create yet another mutable reference and change it again.  All while printing out the variable value (before and after the assignments).

I'll call the original integer variable `cat`; I'll call the first mutable reference `dog`, and the second mutable reference I'll call `bird`.

Here is my code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut cat = 1;
    println!("cat (before) = {}", cat);   // => 1

    // Make a dog so that modifying *dog modifies cat:
    let dog = &mut cat;
    println!("*dog = (before) {}", *dog);   // => 1
    *dog = 22;
    println!("*dog (after) = {}", *dog);   // => 22

    // Make a bird that modyfing *bird modifies both *dog and cat:
    let bird: &mut i32 = dog;   // This line compiles...
    // let bird = dog;          // ...but this line gives a compile error.
    println!("*bird (before) = {}", *bird);   // => 22
    *bird = 333;
    println!("*bird (after) = {}", *bird);   // => 333

    // Print out the values, one final time:
    println!();
    println!("*bird (final) = {}", *bird);   // => 333
    println!("*dog (final) = {}", *dog);   // Won't compile with "let bird = dog;"
    println!("cat (final) = {}", cat);   // => 333
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPNboMwDL73KTwOG1QVVeEGYm8waYdJO4cSWqshqULaqar67MxJaTYittxi@/tzFH3qzTC0EjqGMk7gugA6ghvoTga2zEAFm9IVjxqlEfIpjmw5rnmrNE@of71FKzualDS1XkP1CpuFg9DljR04MGjUDnoFZk/QTjXYXlDuYGnL7oq8txSFl7edCp5HF6GD5b3tTTgLtjjxYDHjZJbNUsSsNVz7EAFDloUxatSND3FpXQZX8yFqZfZ3USabaSQ7WNwjYZ6RJk2NYh977EGg5LBV3REF79M0fWg/sD@I8VCPxmriMx6/wzO5YA8e4FornYbZHV34hK46je82OGrneV7O8wRLDGgI59f4bqGgnGMOZyZOvF@BIt@0SybAYMeLqUjyh6gD/Cs6994B6td7fyr5YvzavpCeMQo2H839gynj9BtYF7dh@AY)

As is, the program compiles and runs just fine.  But take a look at the lines:

```
let bird: &mut i32 = dog;   // This line compiles...
// let bird = dog;          // ...but this line gives a compile error.
```

If you comment out that first line (the one with the `&mut i32` explicit declaration) and un-comment out the second line (`let bird = dog;` -- the one with the implicit declaration), then you will get the following compiler error:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `dog`
```

But why?  Are not those two lines of code essentially the same?

(The explanation for [error E0382](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0382) says that a variable was used after its contents have been moved elsewhere.  I could see how `dog`'s contents could have been moved to `bird`, but after the final usage of `bird`, wouldn't `dog` get its contents back?  Besides, even if `dog` *didn't* get its contents back, how could it work with the explicit `let bird: &mut i32 = dog;` declaration in the first place?)

Sure, the first line explicitly declares the `bird` variable as a mutable reference to an `i32` type, but doesn't the second line do that implicitly?  (Maybe the second line uses `i64` or `u32`, but I don't think that would be a significant difference in this case.)

In other words, we established that `dog` is a mutable reference to an integer at its declaration, so wouldn't writing:

```
let bird = dog;
```

implicitly establish that `bird` is a mutable reference to an integer, just as `dog` is?

Additionally, I'm also puzzled by the following behavior:

Obviously, I can fix the above compiler error by replacing the second line (the one with the implicit declaration) with the first (the one with the explicit declaration).  However, I've also discovered that, instead of doing that, I can remove the compiler error by commenting-out/removing the `println!("*dog (final) = {}", *dog);` line.

In other words, the lines:

```
let bird = dog;
```

and:

```
println!("*dog (final) = {}", *dog);
```

refuse to coexist.  But remove one, and the program compiles and runs just fine.  Why is that?

---

So basically I have two questions:

1. How/why is the implicit declaration `let bird = dog;` different than the `let bird: &mut i32 dog;` declaration?  (Aren't they essentially the same?)
2. Why does the `println!("*dog (final) = {}", *dog);` line work perfectly well with the explicit `let bird: &mut i32 dog;` declaration, but break with the implicit `let bird = dog;` declaration?

---

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It may have the same answer as this Q&A: [Why is the mutable reference not moved here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154387/why-is-the-mutable-reference-not-moved-here) It would explain `let x: &mut _ = y;` is an implicit re-borrow while `let x = y;` is a move.