# How does for loop implement into_iter

Tags: for-loop, rust

Follow up this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72215559/for-loop-and-into-iter) which is marked as duplicate as question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430078/iterate-through-a-mutable-reference-of-vector-without-moving-the-value-from-the/70431955).

The concept of how for loop implement `into_iter` keeps haunt me down and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70431955/19092475) kinda creates more question to me like the terms of **re-borrow**, which is not mentioned in rust official document at all except in [one place](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/types/pointer.html#raw-pointers-const-and-mut).

To my understanding of this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72215559/for-loop-and-into-iter#comment127591093_72215559), when vec is a mutable reference, `for i in vec.into_iter()` is actually `for i in (&mut *vec).into_iter()` behind the scene.

How about `for i in vec`, is it actually `i in vec.into_iter()`? Is there any place that have more detail on how for loop is implemented and how re-borrowing gets triggered and how it works?

Code for reference:

```
fn question1_1(vec: &mut [i32]) {
    for &mut item in vec.into_iter() {
        println!("{}", item);
    }
    for &mut item in vec { // --- `vec` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
        println!("{}", item);
    }
    vec; // Error: move occurs because `vec` has type `&mut [i32]`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut s = vec![1, 2, 3];
    question1_1(&mut s);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do mutable references have move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960584/do-mutable-references-have-move-semantics)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman No, I don't think so. It just explain what happened when mutable reference get passed into function. It doesn't explain how for loop works behind the scene.

Comment: @eggyal `for _ in x` is equal to `for _ in x.into_iter()` is what thought, but they behave differently. How does `IntoIterator` make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loop is desugared into (this can be seen by inspecting the HIR):

```rust
{
    let _t = match IntoIterator::into_iter(iter) {
        mut iter => loop {
            match Iterator::next(&mut iter) {
                None => break,
                Some(i) => {
                    // Body
                }
            }
        },
    };
    _t
}
```

Specifically, the iterable is transformed into an iterator by executing `IntoIterator::into_iter(iterable)`. Each trait, including `IntoIterator`, has a hidden `Self` generic parameter, and so this is actually `IntoIterator::<_>::into_iter(iterable)`. From reborrowing POV, this is similar to:

```rust
fn foo<T>(v: T) {}

foo::<_>(iterable)
```

The exact details are explained in [Do mutable references have move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62961289/7884305), but the general idea is, it is not documented. And the current working is such that when the compiler cannot determine without inference that something is a mutable reference, it is not reborrowed. Since `_` requires inference, it is not reborrowed.

The receiver works differently (always reborrowed), and thus `iterable.into_iter()` does perform reborrowing. In fact, this behavior is related to [autoref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) and not reborrowing. See also [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules).

Comment: What do you mean by HIR, POV, and receiver?

Comment: [HIR](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/hir.html) - High-level Intermediate Representation. It is some form of desugaring rustc uses during the compilation process. You can inspect it for a given program at the playground by clicking the menu (three dots) -> HIR. POV - Point Of View. Receiver - the object you put the dot on, i.e. `receiver.method_name(argument1, argument2, ...)`.

Comment: Just to make sure, receiver is also using `IntoIterator::into_iter,` same as for loop but for loop passed iterable as a parameter to `IntoIterator::into_iter` am I right?

Comment: When you do `iter.into_iter()` explicitly, sure this gets passed into `IntoIterator::into_iter()` by `for` using [the blanket `impl<I: Iterator> IntoIter for I`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.60.0/src/core/iter/traits/collect.rs.html#258-266), but the reborrowing is already performed by the explicit call.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using HIR on playground to inspect how for loop run behind the scene, [Here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#for-loops-and-intoiterator) is the official documentation on how for loop is de-sugared.

From the example given by the document, values (a vec type) was passed into IntoIterator::into_iter() `IntoIterator::into_iter(values)`, which is different than calling as a method `values.into_iter()`.

```
let values = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for x in values {
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

De-sugared into

```
let values = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
{
    let result = match IntoIterator::into_iter(values) {
        mut iter => loop {
            let next;
            match iter.next() {
                Some(val) => next = val,
                None => break,
            };
            let x = next;
            let () = { println!("{}", x); };
        },
    };
    result
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if I am understanding the document incorrectly :)