# Move behind mutable reference in a struct

Tags: rust

I have a struct containing a mutable reference and an owned value. I'm trying to see if I can implement some getters for these values. To my surprise, `getx` compiles but `gety` doesn't. Given that neither `&mut String` nor `String` implements `Copy`, why would the compiler allow getting a `&mut String` but not a `String`?

```
struct S<'a> {
    x: &'a mut String,
    y: String,
}
impl<'a> S<'a> {
    fn getx(&mut self) -> &mut String {
        self.x // Ok
    }
    fn gety(&mut self) -> String {
        self.y // Err
    }
}
```

Error messages:

> error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.y` which is behind a mutable reference

> move occurs because `self.y` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

Comment: `&mut` can be "implicitly reborrowed". Here are some useful resources for understanding: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960584/do-mutable-references-have-move-semantics), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535529/variable-binding-moving-a-mut-or-borrowing-the-referent), [3](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/788)

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks bro they once had some documentation [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.12.0/nomicon/references.html#liveness)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `gety` example you move out of the `String`. You can't do that because the ownership would be given to the caller, leaving the original struct in a partial state (it still needs to be usable because you only borrow yourself mutably via `&mut self`).

As @PitaJ correctly said, the `getx` example works via implicit reborrowing. This concept is not documented enough (and there is an [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/788) for it), but it can be explained pretty easily:

When the compiler knows the type of a variable to be a (mutable) reference, it can be automatically borrowed (mutably). In this case a *reborrow* occurs, meaning that the expression first gets dereferenced like this:

```
fn getx(&mut self) -> &mut String {
    &mut *self.x
}
```

Or, with explicit lifetime annotations:

```
fn getx<'s>(&'s mut self) -> &'s mut String {
    &mut *self.x
}
```

This works, because it returns a mutable reference to the String's contents, but not *the* mutable reference stored in the container.   Because this returns a exclusive reference to the inner String, it is not possible to change the String in another way while this reference is in scope. This is one of the most fundamental aspects of Rust's ownership model.