# Why adding a type annotation eliminates the borrow error?

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker, type-annotation

I was learning Rust and all the references and borrowing stuff when I came across this weird case:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut n = 42u32;

    let ref1 = &mut n; 
    let ref2 = ref1;   // line 5
    
    ref2;
    ref1;              // line 8
}
```

This snippet does not compile since `ref1` is moved in line 5 and can not be used in line 8, which I understand.

But when I added a type annotation (which seems totally extraneous and should not affect anything at all since `rust-analyzer` reports the exactly same type) to ref2:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut n = 42u32;

    let ref1 = &mut n;
    let ref2: &mut u32 = ref1;
    //      ++++++++++
    ref2;
    ref1;
}
```

It suddenly compiles! (You can try it [at the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=68e7e0210095eda9e9a218142691af62))

What is going on? I am currently using rustc 1.65.0, is this some kind of bug? Or is there something I missed?

I tried this using different version of rustc [in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xYofhPP6E) and it seems that 1.36.0 is the first version that successfully compiles the second snippet. So I checked the annocement and noticed they introduced something called 'Non-Lexical Lifetimes' in that version, I am not sure whether this is relevant but I noticed the error msg from rustc 1.35.0 is:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `ref1` because it is borrowed --> 
<source>:9:5  
  |
6 |     let ref2: &mut u32 = ref1;  
  |                          ---- borrow of `*ref1` occurs here
...
9 |     ref1; 
  |     ^^^^ move out of `ref1` occurs here
error: aborting due to previous error
```

which is different from the error for the first snippet that basically says that you can not use `ref1` after it is moved. How can I understand this?

Comment: A small hint is that using let `let ref2 = &mut *ref1;` also compiles. Not that I understand what's going on. I thought it might be NLL-related, but then it should compile from 1.31.

Comment: Ah, this compiles from 1.31 on if you pass `--edition=2018`. And [1.36](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/07/04/Rust-1.36.0.html#nll-for-rust-2015) backported NLL to 2015. Though why rust stops moving and starts borrowing when you specify the type is still beyond me.

Comment: @Caesar Thanks for your hint! I was suspecting the same thing but just could not understand why the compiler does different things when the only difference in the code is an 'innocent' type annotation. I was able to find [a relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535529/variable-binding-moving-a-mut-or-borrowing-the-referent) moments ago but the answer basically says 'yes, I guess adding a type annotation just changes some decisions the compiler makes', which, honestly, does not satisfy me. I wonder whether this is how far we can get.

Comment: Unsatisfying indeed. Though not entirely surprising, there's a few weird rules around let and references. Another example of such a rule is that `let x = &String::new();` compiles just fine, but e.g. `let x = vec![&String::new()];` doesn't if you use `x` later.

Comment: @Caesar I tried your example just now! At first I was guessing whether this has something to do with the `Vec`'s element being stored in heap so the compiler finds it unsuitable that the `Vec`'s element is a reference to something in the stack, but as soon as I created a local variable for `String::new()` and use the reference to the local variable instead, the error disappeared! I guess there is more I can explore about Rust.

Comment: Ah, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960584/do-mutable-references-have-move-semantics) that @Chayim linked explains the implicit reborrows a bit more satisfactorily. Btw, you can also tell rust to do a reborrow by saying `let ref ref2 = ref1;`